# Rails: Is it dangerous to use hidden field tags for money related params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a checkout for an online store. When the customer has filled out his shipping and billing info, it takes them to an order summary page. Here's my action controller for that:

```
def order_summary
  @cart = current_or_guest_user.cart    
  @purchase = current_or_guest_user.incomplete_purchases.last

  if @purchase.shipping_method.uses_ups?
    products = @cart.cart_items.map(&:product)
    ups_shipping = UpsShipping.new(products: products, purchase: @purchase)
    @shipping_rate = ups_shipping.request_shipping_rate
  else
    @shipping_rate = UnitedStatesPostalServiceShipping.calculate_shipping_rate(sub_total: @cart.total)
  end
end
```

`UpsShipping` and `UnitedStatesPostalServiceShipping` are non ActiveRecord models that I wrote to hit external APIs to request a shipping rate. They don't point to any tables in my database.

This they don't have any records in the database, I need a way to persist the value of the @shipping_rate response in the request that follows `order_summary` and store it as `@purchase.shipping_cost`. I'm thinking of either just storing it in the session or putting a hidden field in the view.

Would it be safe for me to have a `<%= hidden_field_tag "purchase[shipping_cost]" @shipping_rate %>` tag in the view? Or would putting that in the session be safer?

Or is hitting the UPS/USPS API another time in the following request the best choice? I am thinking that hitting the APIs again would make my app a little more fragile, which is why I only want to hit it once and store the value. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Session data is saved in a cookie. Not sure if that is any safer?

Comment: Cont: Maybe consider using the openssl library and encrypting the data before putting it on the frontend and then also decrypt when it hits your service.

Comment: You think it'll be okay if I just add 2 lines to the order_summary action: `@purchase.shipping_cost = @shipping_rate; @purchase.save` ? I was trying to avoid saving anything on that page but I guess that works..